# django async support - not fully understanding the main concept

Tags: django, asynchronous, asgi

which is main concept of django asgi?

1. when there are multiple tasks to be done inside a view,
   handle those multiple tasks concurrently thus reduce view's response time.
2. when there are multiple requests from multiple users at same time,
   hendle those requests concurrently thus users wait less in queue.
3. Channels? Web Socket?

I'm trying to understand and use the asgi concept but feeling so lost.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asgi provides an asynchronous/synchronous interface for python applications to interact with front-end web elements (HTML and Scripts). In a sense, because the interface itself handles the requests concurrently, it is working to reduce response time - because it is the reason that that django web servers respond notably quick. Multiple tasks from multiple users are handly quickly and efficiently, but that is not the main concept.

Most importantly, asgi provides a method for python (as well as the django library) to interact with the frontend HTML page we are showing the user. As was the original triumph of wsgi; asgi is the upgrade that allows python to communicate with the web client actively (listening) then start asynchronous tasks that allow us to begin tasks or change values outside of the direct scope of what the application is doing. Thus, we can start those tasks, serve different values to the user, and continue those tasks in the background uninterrupted.