# Django Channels works fine locally but fails in production

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I have a simple chat application using Django and Django Channels. I was following a Django Channels tutorial. It works fine locally but in production it failed.

This is my JavaScript code that opens the websocket:

```js
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
  'ws://'
  + window.location.host
  + '/ws/chat/'
  + roomName
  + '/'
);
```

This is the error raised when going to the chat page:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://site-url.ir/chat/room/1/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://site-url.ir/ws/chat/room_1/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

room.js:18 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

Comment: It's not working in production because you're using `https://` to load the page, but you're connecting to the web socket insecurely. Try changing the `ws://` to `wss://` for production. You can use `window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://'` for this.

Comment: but when that change to wss i got 500 response.

Answer (score 0):

In production, your code must connect to `wss`. However, unless you have created an alternate server running a websocket, you must use something to redirect traffic like Daphne. Daphne is used to run multiple instances or python applications and redirect web traffic on a specific port. The port we are redirecting traffic on must be setup in the server configuration. Please read the [Daphne documentation](https://github.com/django/daphne) for more info.

After you have setup up Daphne, you are going to want to setup your server configuration to redirect traffic to the ports you are using for `https` and `wss`. Remember, each Daphne instance is local to our server, thus we need to redirect all to `wss` to `ws`. Because we are using Daphne to run asynchronous applications, we no longer specify a `WSGIScriptAlias` `WSGIDaemonProcess` or `WSGIProcessGroup` but instead specify the [asgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596618/django-async-support-not-fully-understanding-the-main-concept/67596962#67596962) file to Daphne when we run the server. For example in Apache2:

```
...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
...
```

Then you have to start the server, and so at production level you are going to need a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/) container or some methodology to keep the code running. Make sure to modify the port in production level to match your apache conf.

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:application // Local Development Level
daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem django_project.asgi:application // Production Level
```